# how to use ajax to get data for a PhoneGap application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, get

i've been researching on how to use ajax to get some content from a php file, but i run into some problems. It does not get the data.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//$(document).ready(function () {

    var path = "http://website.com/php/functions.php";

        $( document ).bind('mobileinit', function () {
            $.get(path+'?get_param=value', function (data) {
                $('#pageshow').html(data);
            });
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });
        alert(path+'?get_param=value');
//});
</script>

<div data-role="content">   
    <h1>Hello World</h1>    
    <div id="pageshow">1</div>          
</div><!-- /content -->
```

- if i go to that link in my browser i get the data.
- im not sure if `var path = "http://website.com/php/functions.php";` should be `var path = "php/functions.php";` but all files are in the same folder on the server

any suggestion on how to make this work?

lots of thanks

Comment: what does this mean `.find('#content"]')`, and yes you can use  the url as `/php/functions.php`

Comment: good point, let me revise that

Comment: i thought it was a typo if its not then there you go that is the problem

Comment: nope, that didn't fix it

Comment: have you checked in the firebug for any errors

Comment: im testing the app on my phone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6913/discussion-between-3nigma-and-patrioticcow)

Comment: is that "mobileinit" event triggered on your phone?

Comment: im not sure, should be at the application start, i took the code from the phonegap page

Comment: 3nigma you were right, just that the data should be `get_param: 'value'` and the url was a bit off, need to go 2 directories back. If u port your ajax code ill accept it. thanks

Comment: @Patrioticcow sorry  i got disconnected,

Comment: oh thats nyce .. posted the answer `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `$.get` request to `$.ajax` and make yourself an error handler like

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/php/functions.php',
data: { get_param: value },
success: function (data) {
alert("success");
},
error: function () {
alert("error");
}

});
```

also notice the `data:{get_param:value}` the query string param should be passed like this